# Why is my function only returning the object in the second return statement not the first return statement which is actually triggering the return

Tags: python-3.x, xml, recursion, lxml

I have some xml that has some elements of unknown depth here is an example element

```
<someElement anAttribute="descriptiveandimportant">
<firstChild>
<childOfFirstChild anAttribute="someText">text_value</childOfFirstChild>
</firstChild>
<secondChild>
<daughterOfSecondChild>anotherText_value_1</daughterOfSecondChild>
<sonOfSecondChild>anotherText_value_2</sonOfSecondChild>
</secondChild>
</someElement>
```

I don't know how many children there are of someElement and I don't know how many children each child has . . .  It really doesn't go that deep but I am working with some data in the wild and I can't assume I know all of the children and their children in advance.

I want each unique child element and their children . . .

```
    myOutput = [firstChild, childOfFirstChild, second_child, daughterOfSecondChild, sonOfSecondChild]
```

I wrote a function - the print statements are there to help me sort out the problems

```
def get_children(some_element_list):

    new_elements_list = []

    for e in some_element_list:
        new_elements_list.append(e)
        for child in e.iterchildren():
            if child == e:
                continue
            if child in some_element_list:
                continue
            new_elements_list.append(child)
    print (new_elements_list)

    if new_elements_list == some_element_list:
        print ('passed the test')

        return some_element_list[1:]   # when triggered

    print('going to loop again')
    some_element_list = get_children(new_elements_list) # returns here


    return some_element_list  # if this is not present nothing is returned
```

Here is the result after running the function with someElement

```
>>> y = get_children([someElement])
[<Element someElement at 0x23f4cbbff40>, <Element firstChild at 0x23f4cc76f90>, <Element secondChild at 0x23f4cbbfc70>]
going to loop again
[<Element someElement at 0x23f4cbbff40>, <Element firstChild at 0x23f4cc76f90>, <Element childOfFirstChild at 0x23f4cc76a90>, <Element secondChild at 0x23f4cbbfc70>, <Element daughterOfSecondChild at 0x23f4cc769a0>, <Element sonOfSecondChild at 0x23f4cc76b30>]
going to loop again
[<Element someElement at 0x23f4cbbff40>, <Element firstChild at 0x23f4cc76f90>, <Element childOfFirstChild at 0x23f4cc76a90>, <Element secondChild at 0x23f4cbbfc70>, <Element daughterOfSecondChild at 0x23f4cc769a0>, <Element sonOfSecondChild at 0x23f4cc76b30>]
passed the test
```

I was struggling as I initially had the **final** return statement without naming anything to return - once I named some_element_list in the second return statement the function returns some_element_list[1:] - in other words it returns what is defined in the first return statement.

I never code that some_element_list = some_element_list[1:].

And then finally as I was trying to think how to ask this question - I changed the final return statement to

```
return 'is this not interesting'
```

and that is what is returned - not the some_element_list[1:]

In summary I am seeing two things that don't make sense to me

1. I have to specify some object in the final return statement for the function to return anything - even if the return is triggered before the end of the function.
2. some_element_list is actually some_element_list[1:] if that is how it is defined in the first return statement

based on the answer below and having some distance from the problem I now understand the issue  The comments in the code I hope help explains to the next person who comes along  My mistake was thinking that when the first return is triggered it returned **outside** to the *caller* the explanation below helped me get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic recursion but made confusing because it has `xml` bits added in that are irrelevant to the problem.

The best way I can think to explain it is that this bit:

```
    if new_elements_list == some_element_list:
        return some_element_list[1:]
```

is your base case.

It stops your recursion at an unspecified depth.
However, your result still needs to "bubble" up from your nested calls.
Since this example only recurses twice, it's easy to give you an example of how this occurs.

Assume `some_element_list = get_children(new_elements_list)` ISN'T recursive and it's simply calling another function.
This is how it would look for your case.

```
import lxml.etree

def get_children(some_element_list):
    new_elements_list = []
    for e in some_element_list:
        new_elements_list.append(e)
        for child in e.iterchildren():
            if child == e:
                continue
            if child in some_element_list:
                continue
            new_elements_list.append(child)
    # This can removed since it's actually only ever True in the 
    # recursive call
    # if new_elements_list == some_element_list:
    #     return some_element_list[1:]
    some_element_list = get_children_inner_call(new_elements_list)
    return some_element_list

def get_children_inner_call(some_element_list):
    new_elements_list = []
    for e in some_element_list:
        new_elements_list.append(e)
        for child in e.iterchildren():
            if child == e:
                continue
            if child in some_element_list:
                continue
            new_elements_list.append(child)
    # Since it will be true in this "recursive" call
    # it can be removed here
    # if new_elements_list == some_element_list:
    return some_element_list[1:]

foo = lxml.etree.fromstring(
'''<someElement anAttribute="descriptiveandimportant"> 
<firstChild>
<childOfFirstChild anAttribute="someText">text_value</childOfFirstChild>
</firstChild>
<secondChild>
<daughterOfSecondChild>anotherText_value_1</daughterOfSecondChild>
<sonOfSecondChild>anotherText_value_2</sonOfSecondChild>
</secondChild>
</someElement>
''')

print(get_children(foo))
```

As you can see `some_element_list` is obtained from the inner call which is actually `some_element_list[1:]`. This is then returned to your outer function call.

If you've used recursion before, you've seen this pattern before. But there's a lot of noise in your example which may have led to the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation.  Your explanation matches exactly what is going on I need to think on this more but you gave me the tools

Comment: A little bit of distance and now I get it - when the first return is triggered it is returning to the caller inside the function not outside the function - silly me